PowerDNS issue with reverse DNS for IPv6
I'm setting up reverse DNS for IPv6 using PowerDNS and could use some assistance with a configuration issue.
I successfully created the reverse DNS zone and added a PTR record, but the record is not resolving.
Here’s an overview of the setup:
Domains Table:
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
| id | name                                 | master | last_check | type   | notified_serial | account |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | example1.com                         | NULL   |       NULL | master |      2024091304 | NULL    |
|  2 | example2.com                         | NULL   |       NULL | master |      2024091304 | NULL    |
| 10 | e.f.0.0.1.8.6.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa | NULL   | 1726570929 | NATIVE |            NULL | NULL    |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+

PTR Record Insert Query:

INSERT INTO records (domain_id, name, type, content, ttl, prio, change_date)
VALUES (
    10, -- Reverse DNS zone domain_id
    '2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f.e.0.0.1.0.0.0.8.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa',
    'PTR',
    'host.example2.com',
    3600,
    NULL,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
);

PTR Record Verification:

SELECT * FROM records WHERE type="PTR";```




+-----+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------+
| id  | domain_id | name                                                             | type | content           | ttl  |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------+
| 469 |        10 | 2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f.e.0.0.1.0.0.0.8.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa | PTR  | host.example2.com | 3600 |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------+```

I double-checked the zone and PTR record, but when I perform a reverse lookup for the IPv6 address, it's not resolving.
Any ideas on what could be wrong or missing in the configuration?

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts.
By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license,
for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices).
By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed.
Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: How does deleting work?

The name 2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f.e.0.0.1.0.0.0.8.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa does not appear to belong in the zone e.f.0.0.1.8.6.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa.
The end of the owner name of that record does not match the name of that zone. One or the other is wrong, or they are both right (in some context) but unrelated and there needs to be another zone.
For easier visual identification:
2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f.e.0.0.1.0.0.0.8.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa
                              e.f.0.0.1.8.6.6.f.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa


I updated the record, but the issue is still there. It could be a delegation problem, or maybe I just need to wait for propagation.
